# Has there been an instance where the Tricorder was used to heal?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, episode-identification

I have been reading about the Tricorder on [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Tricorder#):

> A tricorder was a multifunction hand-held device useful for data sensing, analysis, and recording, with many specialized abilities which made it an asset to crews aboard starships and space stations as well as on away missions. [...]
>
> Tricorders were often useful for recording entries in personal or official logs.

Also,

> In the final draft script of TOS: "Miri", a tricorder was used by Spock to ascertain that McCoy wasn't dead.

I remember seeing it being used to treat an injury (it was used to heal a fracture temporarily, but I could be mistaken); though it has been a long time since I have watched *Star Trek*. It was definitely from *Star Trek - The Next Generation*.

Could I have been mistaken? Maybe it was in another sci-fi movie, like *After Earth*, perhaps?

Comment: Are you sure it was a tricorder that was being used to heal rather than another hand-held device like a [dermal regenerator](https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--aw8ZcDE3--/c_fit,fl_progressive,q_80,w_636/19f8ip75k70lvgif.mp4)?

Comment: Any idea on which Star Trek series it was used as such? Who used it on whom?

Comment: The tricorder was no more used for healing injuries than the sonic screwdriver was used for driving screws…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starfleet medical personnel regularly used medical tricorders to assess injuries and illness, often with [a detachable hand scanner](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/memoryalpha/images/3/39/Medical_tricorder_scanner_attachment.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20120802011727&path-prefix=en) that was run over the affected area, but this was only used for diagnosis, not treatment. I do not know of any examples from Star Trek of a tricorder being used to actively treat injuries. You may be thinking of another franchise or remembering a different device being used.